# Getting a new token with Google OAuth refresh token returns invalid grant error

Tags: oauth, refresh-token, google-classroom

I am requesting access to the user's Google Classroom data with the following PHP code block:

```
public function getGoogleClassroomToken(){
  
  if($this->user==null){
    return ["result"=>"error","message"=>"You need to log in to do that!"];
  }

  if ($this->user['gc_token']) {
    return ["result"=>"error","message"=>"User already has access token!"];
  }

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('example.com');
  $client->setAuthConfig('/var/www/client_secret.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSEWORK_STUDENTS);
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY);
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_ROSTERS_READONLY);

  $redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/gc.php';
  $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  return ["result"=>"success","authUrl"=>$authUrl];

}
```

..which seems to work fine. I am then instantiating the Google Client with the following code block:

```
public function getGoogleClassroomClient(){
  if($this->user==null){return false;}
  if (!$this->user['gc_token']) {return false;}
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfig('/var/www/client_secret.json');
  $client->setAccessToken((array)json_decode($this->user['gc_token']));
  
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        var_dump($token);
    }
  }
  
  return $client;
}
```

.. which works fine UNLESS THE TOKEN HAS EXPIRED, in which case the $token variable outputs:

```
array(2) { ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_grant" ["error_description"]=> string(11) "Bad Request" }
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Comment: check that refresh token is not null.  then check that the date and time on the machine you are running this on is in sync with NTP

Comment: Can you confirm that the refresh token is not null, just like @DaImTo has mentioned?

Comment: I can confirm the refresh token is not null

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

As per [the Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) your refresh token can't be null without throwing [this exception](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L304) **refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken** which makes sense because you are calling `$client->getRefreshToken()` and that returns 2 options: [the refresh token or null](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L497).

If you take a look into the [Google Identity Platform: Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs > Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) it seems like your refresh token has expired, there are some possible scenarios:

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
- The client has reached a limit of 50 refresh tokens per account if it's not a service account.

### Reference

[Google API Client for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php)

[Google Identity Platform: Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)